# Обновление страницы после вставки данных

Tags: php, html, javascript

Есть форма в которую вводят данные, дальше нажимаем ок и введенные данные уходят в джаваскиптовый файл.

Форма на странице index.php

```
<form id="'.$row['loadName']. '" method="GET">
<table сlass="value">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="’.$row['loadName'].'-LoadName" name="loadname" type="hidden" value="’.$row['loadName'] ?>’."/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="'.$row['loadName'].'-TestOk" name="testOK" size="10" type="text" value="'.$RowForValues['TestOk'].'"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <input class="buttonValue" name="ValueOK" onClick="requestForValue(readDataForValue,\''.$row['loadName'].'\');" type="button" value="OK"/>
</form>
```

Джаваскрипт data.js

```
function requestForValue(callback, id) {

    var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
            callback(xhr.responseText, id);
        }
    };
    id_Loadname = id + '-LoadName';
    id_TestOk = id + '-TestOk';
    var LoadName = document.getElementById(id_Loadname).value;
    var TestOk = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById(id_TestOk).value);
    xhr.open("GET", "AJAX/value.php?LoadName=" + LoadName + "&TestOK=" + TestOk, true);
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

После чего происходит апдейт этих данных в таблице. Но там условие при котором в одном случае необходимо обновить часть таблицы (это работает), а в другом случае необходимо обновить ВСЮ страницу.

value.php, на которую идет джаваскрипт

```
$dbh = dbConnectForAJAX();
$LoadName = $_GET["LoadName"];
$testok = $_GET["TestOK"];

if (empty($LoadName)) {
    /*запрос на обновление данных*/    
}
else {
    /*запрос на добавление данных*/    
    echo '<a href="javascript:location.reload()">See new data click here</a>';
}
```

Подскажите, как еще можно обновить страницу index.php, не нажимая на ссылку, а чтобы она обновлялась автоматически после добавления данных в БД.

Comment: meta не подойдет?

Comment: @KlyaKsa, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1):

Если хочется сделать все красиво — посмотрите в сторону MVC- или MVVM-фреймворков. Например, Backbone.js, Knockout.js (или оба одновременно, используя Knockback.js), Spine.js, Batman.js и еще много на вкус и цвет, каждый со своими особенностями.

А если хочется быстро сделать чтобы работало и забыть — просто верните с сервера специальную строку, скажем, «`<reload>`», и увидев ее в `xhr.responseText` (или перед вызовом `callback` или в нем, где удобнее) перегружайте всю страницу (`location.reload()`)